# Getting a Time from a specific string in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I'm receiving a string from a JSON form as this :

```
"Thu May 07 2015 08:45:00 GMT+0100 (Afr. centrale Ouest)"
```

I need to transform it to a valid DateTime format then to grab a specific part (Time, Date, and Timezone).

Now I started with this :

```
$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d Y H:i:s T',$starting);
```

to transform it to a DateTime, but this always returns false, can anyone help ?

Comment: `DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d Y H:i:s T', "Thu May 07 2015 08:45:00 GMT+0100");` works fine..

Comment: and by replacing "T" by "e+" ?

Comment: (Afr. centrale Ouest) ?

Comment: `DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d Y H:i:s e+', "Thu May 07 2015 08:45:00 GMT+0100 (Afr. centrale Ouest)");` works well, as suggested by MTroy..

Comment: @MTroy exactly it returned DateTime {#307 ▼
  +"date": "2015-05-09 09:05:00.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 1
  +"timezone": "+01:00"
}

Comment: yes it's at end of table... not easily to find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to [createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) doc

the '+' at the bottom of table... :/
and you'll be able to ignore the rest of string (timezone abbrev..)

> If this format specifier is present, trailing data in the string will
>   not cause an error, but a warning instead

Note from php manual:

> Use DateTime::getLastErrors() to find out whether trailing data was
>   present.